# How can I run a function into an Object by your key name in TypeScript?

Tags: javascript, typescript, typescript-typings, typescript2.0

I have an Object like this:

```
const Foo = {
    bar: (): void => { console.log('foo.bar') },
    baz: (): void => { console.log('foo.baz') },
};
```

I would like to call these functions this way:

```
Foo["bar"]();
Foo["baz"]();
```

Unfortunately, TypeScript doesn't compile this code.

`Element implicitly has an 'any' type because expression of type 'string' can't be used to index type {MY_OBJECT}`

What do I need to do to enable the function call by the index name?

**#EDIT**

I create this snippet to show the problem:

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/MYewdgzgLgBAtgUwhAhgcwQLhtATgSzDRgF4YByACwQBsaQYB3EXGgE3IG4AoUSWDFACCEUjAA8AFQB8AChAAjAFYJgUbCjABPAJTZJpaTEUq1MFKMk8+EEDQQA6emlmJk6BDuvhb9pyBdBEXE8QjQ5AEYAJgBmHS8gA)

Comment: actually it should work that way. The link to the playground is missing the playground.

Comment: You can run with ctrl+enter, the script will run, but the error is show in the screen.

Comment: There is no code in the playground — have a look at the playground link, it should contain the serialized content of your playground, now it has nothing but a #.

Comment: @KarolMajewski I think that was some SO filter. I update the question with the link, I hope that keeps this way now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The code you provided works as-is, at least in typescript `3.9.2`. It's possible though that either 1. it does not work that way in an earlier version of TS, or 2. the code you provided was simply an example and isn't exactly the code you have trouble with.

In either case, the error has to do with `string` and subtypes of `string` (`bar` and `baz`).

Your object `Foo`'s type is inferred as:

```js
{ [key in 'bar' | 'baz']: () => void }
```

as opposed to

```js
{ [key in string]: () => void }
```

or in other words, the keys can only be specific sub-types of `string`.

When you run `Foo["bar"]();`, the latest typescript should correctly interpret the index provided as `'bar'`, but an earlier version might not be doing so.

You can get around this by forcing TS to interpret this as a literal type using a [const assertion](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-4.html#const-assertions) like so:

```js
const key1 = 'bar' as const
Foo[key1]() // should not error

const key2 = 'baz' as const
Foo[key2]() // should not error
```

Alternatively, you can provide a type annotation to your `Foo` object with a wider type like so:

```js
const Foo: {[key in string]: () => void} = {
    bar: (): void => { console.log('foo.bar') },
    baz: (): void => { console.log('foo.baz') },
};

Foo['bar']() // should not error
Foo['baz']() // should not error
```

Comment: Thank you George, your answer helps me. Indeed, the code runs, but the error still appears in the compiler, you can take a look in the playground link.